# Trouble rendering Css Data in Django?

Tags: css, django, pdf

So I'm trying to export a section of a website to PDF, and I'm able to output the HTML data properly, but the CSS codes just appears as text in the PDF.

```
>

 def exportPDf(results, css, html):
>           
>           result = StringIO.StringIO()
>           
>           results_2 = StringIO.StringIO(results.encode("UTF-8"))
>           css_encode = StringIO.StringIO(css.encode("UTF-8"))
>           
>           pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(results_2 , result)#ISO-8859-1
>           
>           if not pdf.err:
>               return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), mimetype='application/pdf')
>           return HttpResponse('We had some errors<pre>%s</pre>' % escape(html))
>           
>     def get_data(request):
>           results = request.GET['css'] + request.GET['html']
>           html = request.GET['html']
>           css = request.GET['css']
>           return ExportPDf(results, css, html)
```

Again, the HTML is fine. IT's just the css part that doesn't render. It outputs the actual CSS codes to PDF.

Comment: Posting the relevant parts of your code will help others to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you've setup your CSS as such:

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        color:#fff;
    }
</style>
```

Try wrapping your css with comments:

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--
    body {
        color:#fff;
    }
-->
</style>
```

This will force the CSS as a comment and thus won't render.  Since I can't see how your code is rendered this is just a guess but let me know if it does indeed work :)

Comment: I get your what you're trying to tell me but that's not what I want. When I export to PDF, the CSS is outputted as literally text. Like, h1{background: purple;} etc...... While the HTML code is read and "executed". I want the CSS to be "executed" too.  I'm not sure if I'm explaining myself properly =/ lol.

Comment: hmmmmm sorry I missed that!  I just had a gander at the documentation from Django Project and ReportLab (the people that made the PDF library) and it would seem they don't actually parse the CSS and use it to render the page (it appears they have their own means and will only use attributes from html that aren't styles such as valign, width, etc.).  HOWEVER, I did find a python library that takes CSS into account here http://www.xhtml2pdf.com/ that looks pretty promising.  Hope that helps!